# Creating a graph from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension, graphing

I'll start with my usual preamble: I'm fairly new to Python and have been trying to graph something with limited success. I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on how I need to be structuring the data to make my life a little easier.

What I have: I have accessed an API and formatted the data as a list of lists as shown below in `mydata`. The 0th element of each 'sub-list' represents the year and the 1st element of the 'sub-lists' represent the value I would like to plot.

`mydata = [[[2005, 4.4795], [2006, 4.4271], [2007, 4.3048], [2008, 4.0818]], [[2007, 1.0841], [2008, 8.8946]]]`

What I want: The data in each of the lists represent two separate entities. For one, we have information from 2005 through 2008. For the other, we have information from 2007 to 2008. I would like to take the data from above and plot graphically for the years 2007 and 2008 (there will be more years after I figure out how to do these two years).

So far I haven't been able to properly index and store the data in a manner that is conducive to graphing. The following code that accesses all the 1st elements of the 'sub-lists' is as far as I have been able to get. If you run it you will clearly see that this doesn't index to just 2007 and 2008 and that it doesn't store the data in a way that would allow for easy graphing.

`for element in mydata:
    for x in element:
        print x[1]`

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you need `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access data of JUST 2007 and 2008, you will have to search by those two years' index.
I mean, you have to know in which index those years are stored in.
In this case, index-1 is the answer.
So, you have to loop for each 'sub-list' of index-1 as below:

```
for element in mydata[1]:
    print element[1]     #print value of year 2007 and 2008


OUTPUT:
1.0841
8.8946
```

I think, this was what you asked. If not, please let's know.